# MongoDB for a viral website. AWS + MongoDB a good solution?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

We're considering MongoDB for a website we expect to go viral (think millions of users within the first 1-2 months).

We're going to need lots of memory because we need this to be fast.  We're looking at 32 GB of memory at the minimum.  The problem with dedicated servers is that the monthly cost for 32-64 GB of memory is sky high.

The main benefit with AWS is that you pay as you go/scale.

I looked at the Amazon EC2 "High-Memory Double Extra Large Instance" and it has 34.2 GB of memory and 850 GB storage.

The website will be a Twitter-like website which will be heavy on status updates - but it doesn't restrict to 160 characters (potentially unlimited characters).

The tricky part is how the Twitter homepage has a list of all the latest tweets from people you are following.  I expect that Twitter has two tables/"collections:" one that holds the tweets you tweeted, and a separate one that holds the tweets you've received (but wouldn't that mean they are doing thousands to hundreds of thousands of DB writes every time someone with tons of followers posts a status update?)

Backend uses Node.js so MongoDB is ideal.

My questions are:

1) Do we need 32 GB of memory in our situation?
2) Is the 850 GB of storage space provided by EC2 enough?
3) Is EC2 or a dedicated server better for MongoDB hosting of status updates? Why?

Comment: for reference, 1 million hits per month is 23 hits per minute, on average. Almost every webserver on the planet can handle easily 23 hits per second. That's 60 million hits per month, averaged. You need to define your metric A LOT BETTER. "I expect 10,000 hits per minute" (sustained that's 432,000,000 hits in a month). That's a lot better performance metric to hit. A million a month is not very scale-worthy.

Comment: OP says millions of users, not millions of hits. That would probably raise the expected traffic to something closer to your 432 million.

Comment: Also, "a separate one that holds the tweets you've received". Dear god, I hope that's not how you've built your site.

Answer (score 4):

1. Once you actually have the users, you need as much memory as the size of your active data set. Right now that's 0GB, so don't go buying all those instances just yet.
2. Do you have more than 850GB of data to store? Are you building a copy of the library of congress? Unless those millions of users are going to be uploading large binary objects, why do you even ask if 850GB is enough?
3. Both would work fine, but having your own hardware gives you more control. You can certainly beat the IO performance of AWS with your own RAID arrays or SAN. If you can't fit your entire database in RAM, then disk IO is your primary bottleneck.
4. Is AWS the right choice when you're already complaining about price? Absolutely not. You'll spend far, far less either renting a server or building one yourself and colocating it in a datacenter. ECC RAM for server costs around $25 per gigabyte to buy; it'll probably cost you more than $25 per gigabyte *per month* when configuring something to rent. Would you like to construct one $1500 server once, or pay Amazon $720 *per month* for the same thing?

What you should *probably* do, realistically, is get yourself a $20 per month VPS. That'll get you half a gig of RAM or so. Write your site. Start your promotion. When you have real users and they've created more than half a gig of database records, upgrade to a bigger VPS. It's a push-button 5 minute process you do one night at most VPS hosts like Linode. When you outgrow their larger instances, you build yourself or rent yourself a server of your own. At this point you have an actual need and know enough about how your application performs to know what specs you really need.

There's one point I missed: Why MongoDB? Is there a reason you think an RDBMS like MySQL or SQL Server is wrong for your application, but wasn't wrong for Facebook, wasn't wrong for Twitter, wasn't wrong for MySpace, wasn't wrong for eBay, wasn't wrong for just about any large scale site you can name?

The only recognizable name that scaled quickly and did it with MongoDB recently was foursquare, and their MongoDB setup crashed and burned. When it failed, and it failed mostly because it's not a proven technology and they didn't fully understand how it worked in a distributed at-scale environment, despite having 32 highly technical employees, they were down for *11 hours* figuring out how to piece it back together.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that the answer to this question is "who knows?". We have no idea what your data access patterns are like, are you going to be running caches in front of this db server? How many? In what configuration? How frequently are you going to be writing data? How important is the data, how frequently must it be flushed to disk? If you're really going to be getting 2 million hits then you may well run into bandwith issues before you hit memory issues but again it depends on how efficient your updates are.

When building a site on the scale of twitter you're going to have to spend a ton of time benchmarking your solutions. Likely you'll end up running dozens if not hundreds of servers not just to maintain scale but also to deal with redundency. Believe me twitter didn't come up with their architecture overnight nor did they just cobble together a bunch of off the shelf components. They have been tweeking and optimizing for years writing a lot of the high performance parts themselves.

A good place to start is by reading the high scalability blog over at http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you ever get enough visitors to push your webserver to the limit, you might be much better of with multiple smaller servers; some who just build and serve the webpages, some who just cache prebuild pages and multiple database servers with replication. This way you also would not have one single point of failure.

I also don't see the point in 850GB storage for "status updates". Assuming each Update would be 1kb text, this would be enough for 891.289.600 Updates, or 821 Updates for each user if you hit 1 million (active) users.